# Simple Android Licensing

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I am about to release a paid app on the market and have used licensing to help secure it. I am currently testing with the white-list and have found that if I set it to licenced it works fine, no problems. If I then turn off wireless and data on my mobile I can only open the app once without it saying that it is not licenced.

So basically, the second time I open my app after turning off all internet access to my phone, it is treated as unlicensed. I thought that using the ServerManagedPolicy you could open the app quite a few times with no internet access? What is going on here?

Comment: I had the exact same question, see Snicolas 's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142307/is-my-android-licensing-working-as-it-should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get such behavior because you test it using a developer or test account. When you publish it and users buy it license validity period and retry count will increase.

Comment: Ah right, I just assumed it was the same whether or not you were using a developer account. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's cached for 1 minute if you are a test account, as no VT part is sent in the license response. From memory, this also varies depending on whether you've uploaded a draft apk. Either way, I think there's a log statement which explains what is happening.